# In C++, what happens when you return a variable?

Tags: c++, return-value, copy-constructor

What happens, step by step, when a variable is returned. I know that if it's a built-in and fits, it's thrown into rax/eax/ax. What happens when it doesn't fit, and/or isn't built-in? More importantly, is there a guaranteed copy constructor call?

edit: What about the destructor? Is that called "sometimes", "always", or "never"?

Comment: Depends on the operating system's conventions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where the return value is stored depends entirely on the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and is very architecture- and system-specific.

The compiler is permitted to elide the call to the copy constructor (i.e., it does not have to call the copy constructor).  Note that returning a value from a function might also invoke an assignment operator, depending on what is being done with the return value of a function.

Comment: Is the destructor ever called for the local version?

Comment: @wowus:  No, because there isn't really a "local version."  If the call to the copy constructor is elided, then the object being returned is constructed in-place in the return value.

Comment: @wowus: If there's no copy, calling the destructor will make that instance invalid.

Comment: What about code like...

    T f()
    {
        T a;
        return a;
    }

Comment: @wowus:  That might or might not invoke the copy constructor.  I would expect that an unoptimized build (e.g., for debugging) would invoke the copy constructor, but an optimized build would not.  It's entirely up to the compiler and what it decides is the most reasonable thing to do.  If the copy constructor is not called, then obviously the destructor can't be called, per what @KennyTM and I said.

Comment: So if the copy constructor is called it is guaranteed to have a destructor call?

Comment: @wowus:  Yes, because all local objects are destroyed at the end of the block (e.g. when a function returns).  If one of those objects is copied to be returned, then the local object still needs to be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

If the function/method return type is a reference then effectively no copying takes place.  If it is a non-reference return type, then a copy *may* take place depending on the calling convention of your platform.

In register-rich (typically RISC) architectures there may be a generous allocation of registers to hold modestly large return constructs.  This is to avoid excessive memory transactions which are expensive compared to cache/register transactions.

On the x86-descended intel family which your question implies by the registers you mention, it is more likely than on a RISC to invoke a copy constructor.